# Unfamiliar C++ data type / structure?

Tags: c++

I stumbled upon this syntax while revising for my final exams in Informatics.

```
 int x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

What exactly does this represent? Is it an array or something else?
I don't usually code in C++, but I have the basic knowledge of its syntax and I never saw this syntax before.

Comment: where did you find this? Its an ordinary `int` called `x` with a confusing initializer that uses the comma operator.

Comment: The `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` yields `5`.  The other expressions are evaluated, then discarded.  (If they have side-effects, the side-effects will happen, in the correct order.)

Comment: Can you give me the name of this particular way of declaring variable, so I can search it up more?

Comment: fwiw, when a declaration starts with `int x = ..` then its an `int` not anything else

Comment: there is no name for this particular use of the comma operator because one would not write it like this. The line should not pass a code review.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number well aware of that, but is it an int array, or something else, how does it work and what value does it produce?

Comment: You may be interested in the hour long presentation [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis at CppCon 2018.

Comment: see the duplicate. Its an `int` not an int array or something else.

Comment: It's the same as writing `int x = 5;`, but written in an intentionally confusing way

Comment: If you encounter something like this on an actual exam, then it's a terrible exam question. You would *never* see code like this in the wild. It's a question that only exists to confuse, not to demonstrate actual knowledge about C++.